# How can I define the shortcut icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, electron, windows-installer, package.json

I've created a msi file to install a program. Everything works fine except for the shortcut icon created after the installation.

I already put the icon.icon into build folder. And already set the icon into the icon and manifest of Visual Studio properties.

I expected a icon on the created shortcut, but it creates without any icon on it. If I look into the remove program it shows the correct icon and in the start menu it shows correctly too.

I'm using in the package.json the following code (reduced just to show):

````
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ],
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.comunicacao",
    "copyright": "Contact Center",
    "files": [
      "www/**/*",
      "main.js"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": "msi"
    },
    "msi": {
      "artifactName": "Conectiva-News",
      "perMachine": true,
      "oneClick": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "build": "npm run env.prod && stencil build && npm run fix-electron-path && electron-builder",
    "start": "npm run env.dev && stencil build --dev --watch --es5 --serve",
    "start-electron": "nodemon --watch * --exec electron .",
    "env.dev": "node ./src/env/env-dev-task.js",
    "env.prod": "node ./src/env/env-prod-task.js",
    "fix-electron-path": "node ./src/env/fix-electron-path.js"
  }
}```
````

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `icon.ico`, if that's the case, make sure you didn't misspell it where you assigned it.

Also, I'm not sure if it's the same for c# (as it is for javascript), but you can try adding `--icon=path-to-icon/icon.ico` to your build script in your package.json.